# Convert ByteArray to ShortArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, bytebuffer

I have byte arrays with audio data in Kotlin/Java.

When I use following code The ShortBuffer is created but the short[] inside is is null.

```
    var short1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(samples.data).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer()
```

when I invoke fucntion `.array()` its impossible to convert as short[] is null in buffer.

I'm operating with arrays/buffers in a wrong way?

Sample data is byte[] that contains Audio data in Android WebRtc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `array()` method of `ShortBuffer` is an optional operation and will work **only** when the `ShortBuffer` is backed by a short array (`short[]`).

> [public final short[] array()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ShortBuffer.html#array--)
>
> Returns the short array that backs this buffer  (optional operation).
>
> Modifications to this buffer's content will cause the returned array's
> content to be modified, and vice versa.
>
> Invoke the hasArray method before invoking this method in order to
> ensure that this buffer has an accessible backing array.

since your `ShortBuffer` **is not** backed by a `short[]`, because is created by a `ByteBuffer`, the `array()` method will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

you can use the [`hasArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ShortBuffer.html#hasArray--) method to check whether is safe to call `array()`.